# convert firestore data to string to display, in inner html

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, sveltekit

I Want to display my data in this `<p>` element but I don't know how. I can get it and then console  log it but that's it right now, I got it to display document id but when I go further than that it throws errors

```
 <script>
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
        import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
        import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
        import { onMount } from 'svelte';
        import { collection, addDoc, onSnapshot, getDocs, doc, getDoc, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"; 
    
        let db;
        onMount(async() => {
        const firebaseConfig = {
          ////
        };
      
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        db = getFirestore(app);
    
     
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "songs"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = doc.data();
    });
    
      });
      
    
        </script>
    <p id="data">LOADING...</p>
```

Comment: @SergeySosunov yeah thanks, thats pretty much all I needed, do you know away for me to do this for each piece of data and dynamically generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = doc.data();
});
```

you can use this:

```
const items = querySnapshot.docs.map(x => ({id: x.id, data: x.data()}))
const resultString = JSON.stringify(items, null, 2);
document.getElementById('data').innerText = resultString;
```

Also, add this style to your `<p>`: `style="white-space: pre-wrap;"`

Updates: for something more fancy you can create a function for each of your items that will return some html markup.

```
function getRecordTemplate(record) {
  return `
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <h1><b>${record.data.artist}</b></h1>
      <h5>Id: ${record.id}</h5>
      <p>Song: ${record.data.song}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  `;
}

const blockNodes = items.map((x) => getRecordTemplate(x)).join("");
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = blockNodes;
```

BUT: Change your `<p>` to `<div>`.

[image: Edit kind-rgb-6b33vo]

Note: in codesandbox you will need to "reload" built-in browser with button if you change something in it.

Comment: I have a questions as Im not to familiar with javascript but what does the "2" or the "null" mean in "(items, null, 2);"

Comment: I have looked around the documentation, thanks for explaining would you happen to know the best way to remove all of the {} and [] and such to make it look cleaner?

Comment: I think wrapped in divs would suit my needs for now as I'm not 100% sure of what I want it to be... if you want you can check out the [site](https://groovy-songs.vercel.app/submisions)

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY I don't understand how some people are so talented and helpful :) thank you very much